# Composite vs. Bean CDI - Como acessar métodos do bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, cdi

Estou tentando criar um componente para receber a foto do perfil do usuário. Mas para isso eu preciso fazer o componente acessar
os métodos dentro do Bean CDI da página em questão. Estou fazendo algo assim:

**Criando o componente:**

```
<composite:interface displayName="profilePhoto">
<composite:attribute name="mBean" type="br.com.fm.modelo.abstracts.ProfilePhoto" required="true"
shortDescription="Bean que gerencia esta página." />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
[...cut...]
<p:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.mBean[fecharFotoDialog]}"/>
[...cut...]
</composite:implementation>
```

**Criando o Bean:**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroUsuario extends ProfilePhoto implements Serializable {
public void fecharFotoDialog() {
System.out.println("Entrei nesse treco aqui...");
}
}
```

**Chamando o componente no primefaces:**

```
<t:profilePhoto mBean="#{cadastroUsuario}"/>
```

O que eu espero que aconteça? Que ao clicar no botão que está no componente o método `fecharFotoDialog()` seja chamado.

Alguma direção sobre onde estou errando?

Agradecido,

Comment: Assim não funciona? `action="#{cadastroUsuario.fecharFotoDialog()}"`

Comment: @Douglas você se refere a colocar isso onde? Na implementation do composite ou no componente <t:profilePhoto>?

Comment: Na implementation.

Comment: @Douglas, Não funciona. Mas mesmo assim, o composite não pode ter o nome do Bean hardcoded, ele tem que receber isso na hora da implementação do componente.

Comment: Já tentei fazer assim também:
<composite:attribute name="mbean" required="true"
  shortDescription="Bean que gerencia esta página."/>

Comment: As respostas parecem simples para essa pergunta, mas realmente não funcionam. Nem ao menos aparece uma exceção. Tem esse exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018539/passing-a-backing-bean-instance-as-parameter-to-composite-component

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que por não se tratar de um @ManegedBean os escopos do JSF não funcionaram corretamente.

Tente utilizar algum dos escopos do CDI:

1. ApplicationScoped - O estado do bean permanece durante o ciclo de vida da aplicação.
2. SessionScoped - O ciclo de vida do Bean é vinculado a sessão do usuário.
3. RequestScoped - Será criado um novo Bean a cada requisição.
4. Dependent - Depende de escopo de quem injeta o Bean.
5. ConversationScoped - Permite que o Bean transite entre um ciclo de vida RequestScoped e um SessionScoped de forma programática.

Obs.: Estes escopos estão no pacote javax.enterprise.context

Comment: É meu amigo, não funciona.